# Libtool: Makefile.am call a Makefile in some other directory

Tags: gcc, compilation, autoconf, automake, libtool

Deal All,

I have a library that is built with libtool. I have an additional module that has been built using a Makefile but not using libtool. I want to be able to use this library object along with the ones that libtool builds. Since I do not want to integrate the additional module with libtool, I just want to expand the Makefile generated from libtool on the lines of:

```
all: all-am
```

(instead:)

```
all: new-module all-am 

new-module: 
    -cd new-module-src && $(MAKE)
```

Thanks

How can I do this in the Makefile.am?

Comment: Hi All, any idea how I can solve my problem?

Comment: Can I ask why *not*? `libtool`, even without support from the other autotools can abstract away a lot platform-dependent issues.